# Continuing Error message on root login

Tags: 14.04

i just enabled root login for ssh (can only access it via local network), what worked fine.
now i have the problem when login in as root tho, that following message comes over and over again, even when i apport it via ctrl-c, it just starts over again.
how can i stop this? thx in advance.

```
root@mastermind:/opt# 2016 Mar  3 13:44:53 mastermind failure for localhost motion 1457009093 Can't locate Convert/BER.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Convert::BER module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/share/perl5/Mon/SNMP.pm line 118.
2016 Mar  3 13:44:53 mastermind calling alert mail.alert for localhost/motion (/usr/lib/mon/alert.d/mail.alert,) Can't locate Convert/BER.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Convert::BER module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/share/perl5/Mon/SNMP.pm line 118.
2016 Mar  3 13:44:53 mastermind fatal: mon(114): No recipient addresses found in message header
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search:

```
$ apt-cache search snmp-session
libsnmp-session-perl - Perl support for accessing SNMP-aware devices
```

To install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsnmp-session-perl
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The system logger, `rsyslogd`, is configured to send messages to anyone logged on as root.

The error should be dealt with by fixing the program not trying to hide the error message.

The `you may need to install the Convert::BER module` message suggests you should try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install libconvert-ber-perl
```

Once you do that you will fix only one issue and may have many more or maybe not because errors are somewhat serialized in that each fix only gets you to the next error.

Answer (score 0):

thx for your fast help.. that one worked, as you mentioned, i got another message, can you help me with this too pls?
Thx again

```
root@mastermind:~# 2016 Mar  3 14:16:13 mastermind failure for localhost motion 1457010973 Can't locate object method "new" via package "SNMP::Session" (perhaps you forgot to load "SNMP::Session"?) at /usr/lib/mon/mon.d/process.monitor line 50.
```

2016 Mar  3 14:16:13 mastermind calling alert mail.alert for localhost/motion (/usr/lib/mon/alert.d/mail.alert,) Can't locate object method "new" via package "SNMP::Session" (perhaps you forgot to load "SNMP::Session"?) at /usr/lib/mon/mon.d/process.monitor line 50.
2016 Mar  3 14:16:13 mastermind fatal: mon(114): No recipient addresses found in message header

Answer (score 0):

it shows the same error as before :(

```
root@mastermind:~# 2016 Mar  3 14:40:33 mastermind failure for localhost motion 1457012433 Can't locate object method "new" via package "SNMP::Session" (perhaps you forgot to load "SNMP::Session"?) at /usr/lib/mon/mon.d/process.monitor line 50.
```

2016 Mar  3 14:40:33 mastermind calling alert mail.alert for localhost/motion (/usr/lib/mon/alert.d/mail.alert,) Can't locate object method "new" via package "SNMP::Session" (perhaps you forgot to load "SNMP::Session"?) at /usr/lib/mon/mon.d/process.monitor line 50.
2016 Mar  3 14:40:34 mastermind fatal: mon(114): No recipient addresses found in message header